# Highcharts - two different values are being overlapped

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
Highcharts.chart('graphDiv', {
            chart: {
                type: 'area',
            },
            title: null,
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apr 2020'],
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                    symbolRadius: 4
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    enable: false,
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    stickyTracking: false,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 5 ,
                        lineColor: null,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                radius: 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            },
            series: [
{
    name : 'A',
    data : [0.00060660]
},
{
    name : 'B',
    data : [0.00013098]
},
{
    name : 'C',
    data : [0.00000024]
},
{
    name : 'D',
    data : [0.00010992]
}]        
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/RajKumari_1/gcak756f/7/

In this jsfiddle, C -> 0.00000024, D -> 0.00010992 are different values but they are overlapped. When hovered over the 'C' in legend, the data point is visible.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to use your dataset with ordered points it will show up on plot

```js
series: [
{
    name : 'A',
    data : [0.00060660]
},
{
    name : 'B',
    data : [0.00013098]
},
{
    name : 'C',
    data : [0.00010992]
},
{
    name : 'D',
    data : [0.00000024]
}]
```